# Dynamic sub-groupping within a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there any simpler/more correct way to assign dynamic group?
Let's saq we have following df:

```
group    days(int, >0)
  A        1
  B        12
  A        14
  A        16
  A        19
  B        23
  C        92
  C        12
```

I'd like to assign subgroups based on the following rules:

```
if days >20 then subgroup = 4
if days <= 20 then subgroup = 3
if days <= 10 then subgroup = 2
if days == 0 then subgroup = 1
```

Here is how i do it now:

```
df['subgroup'] = 4
df.loc[df['days'] >20,'subgroup'] = 4
df.loc[df['days'] <=20,'subgroup'] = 3
df.loc[df['days'] <=10,'subgroup'] = 2
df.loc[df['days'] ==0,'subgroup'] = 1
df = df.reset_index()
df['dynamic_subgroup'] = df.groupby(['group'])['subgroup'].rank(method='dense')
```

The resulting table is this one:

```
group    days(int, >0)     dynamic_subgroup
  A        1                    1
  B        12                   1
  A        14                   2
  A        16                   3
  A        19                   4
  B        23                   2
  C        92                   2
  C        12                   1
```

I wonder if there is any easier/better way to achieve same results in Pandas? Generally, any correction to the code appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for binning:

```
bins = [-1, 0, 10, 20, np.inf]
labels=[1,2,3,4]
df['subgroup'] = pd.cut(df['days'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)
  group  days subgroup
0     A     1        2
1     B    12        3
2     A    14        3
3     A    16        3
4     A    19        3
5     B    23        4
6     C    92        4
7     C    12        3
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael ! But then i still need to use `rank`, correct? I just wonder if i can get this dynamic group with jut one operation..

Comment: Yes, then need `groupby` + `rank`.If need rank by method dense need `df['dynamic_subgroup'] = df.groupby(['group'])['subgroup'].rank(method='dense')`. But if need count groups only, need `df['dynamic_subgroup'] = df.groupby(['group']).cumcount()`, but output is different as `rank`

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`searchsorted`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
df.assign(subgroup=np.searchsorted([0, 10, 20], df.days.values) + 1)

  group  days  subgroup
0     A     1         2
1     B    12         3
2     A    14         3
3     A    16         3
4     A    19         3
5     B    23         4
6     C    92         4
7     C    12         3
```

Comment: thanks! But this doesn't assign subgroup 1 to any entry of group A. The idea is that dynamic subgroup will be 1,2,3, etc, see expected result in my question.